# Why macOS filesystem watchers are slower than Linux and doesn't work in WebStorm?

Tags: macos, filesystems, watch, file-watcher, apfs

I'm using Webpack with HMR (Hot Module Reload) that allows to rebuild my source code on the fly and to update the loaded application right in-browser. It uses filesystem watchers (through [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)) to monitor the actual changes.

I've noticed that changes are detected considerably faster on my Linux machine (Ubuntu with ext4 filesystem) than on the macOS one (High Sierra 10.13.6). What are the underlying reasons behind this? Is there a way to maybe speed up the FS-watchers on macOS somehow?

I also see that WebStorm IDE doesn't recognize external filesystem changes on macOS (I have to manually tell IDE to read changes from the FS) while they are perfectly recognized under Linux. It looks like macOS has some real problems with FS watchers. What is the story behind this?

Comment: Have you got something? I have the same problem.